# Has this constructible property of structures in model theory been studied?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, universal-property

I was looking into model theory where a first-order language can be interpreted with a structure and a variable assignment.

Here is an example of a FOL with interpretation:

We have terms:

> Atomic Terms: are constants such as zero
>
> Generative Terms: for each term t: suc(t) is a term
>
> Variable terms: Variables are terms. They are free until captured and turned into bounded variables by a formula.

We have formulas:

> Atomic formula: are relations such as isEven, isNotZero
>
> Generative formula:
>
> If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formula, so is $\phi \wedge \psi$
>
> If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formula, so is $\phi \vee \psi$
>
> If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formula, so is $\phi \Rightarrow \psi$
>
> If $\phi$ is a formula, so is $\neg \phi$
>
> If $\phi$ is a formula, so is $\exists x. \phi$
>
> If $\phi$ is a formula, so is $\forall x. \phi$

An intepretation gives meaning to the terms and relations. (And from there formulas can also be interpreted).

> Universe: $\mathbb{Z}$
>
> $I(zero) = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> $I(Suc(t)) = I(t) + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> $isEven(t) = I(t) \equiv_2 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$

First, I was wondering, is the following property applied to interpretations studied anywhere:

$\forall u \in \text{Universe}. \exists t \in \text{Terms}_\text{without variables} . u = I(t)$

For example, -1 cannot be directly constructed without variable terms.

-1 can only be made accessible using the exists quantifier.
$\exists m . suc(m) = zero$

And if you want uniqueness you can use this trick:
$\wedge \forall m', m''. suc(m') = zero \wedge suc(m'') = zero \implies m' = m''$

Thus second, I was wondering if the following property is studied and if it has a name in the literature:

Structures for which each element in the universe can be determined uniquely using the existential quantifier trick.

Comment: REVIEW: You should put your quotes/citations/borowed sentences like:
> (the quote)
not:
```
(the quote)
```
which is for code lines

Comment: Also please use Mathjax pour greak letters. Globally it is a good question for a first one, I put an upvote. If you more informations don't hesitate to read the brand new  $\color{red}{\mathrm{Quick \ beginner \ guide \ for \ asking \ well \ received \ questions}}$ (link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/1107523). Have a nice day !

Comment: Done, have a nice day as well.

Comment: I think you're looking for [Herbrand models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe).

Comment: Thanks, that was it :-)